# Grub error: unknown filesystem (my filesystem is fine I think)

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, grub

I have somehow broken GRUB. Everytime I boot, I get

```
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescure> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescure> ls (hd0,msdos4)
(hd0,msdos4): Filesystem is unknown
grub rescure> ls (hd0,msdos3)
(hd0,msdos3): Filesystem is unknown
grub rescure> ls (hd0,msdos2)
(hd0,msdos2): Filesystem is unknown
grub rescure> ls (hd0,msdos1)
(hd0,msdos1): Filesystem is unknown
```

But

- When I boot an Arch Linux live ISO, I can mount all my partitions without any problems
- The part_gpt, part_msdos and ext2 modules are loaded in GRUB (my drive is msdos and the linux partition is ext2)

So I don't know what this error means. Maybe if someone know how to get a more verbose error, that would be super helpful.

It occurred after I ran `grub-install` again while trying to change some settings in GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

My hard drive was too large for my old motherboard. When I used the boot firmware, the partition that contains grub was not loaded, because it was around 2Tb away from the start of the drive.

I could somewhat fix it by running `grub-install --disk-module=native`, which uses grub's native disk module instead of the firmware to load the disk. Unfortunately, this breaks windows for me: `error: device format ata0,msdos1 invalid: must be hdN`. What worked for me was to put a partition with grub at the start of the drive and then only load the native disk module in the menu entry that boots linux.